# SerialPort not detected on Linux but on Windows

Tags: python, linux, serial-port, embedded-linux, pyserial

I will develop a Software which need to detect a Serial Device via a USB Port, on Windows everything work fine, but on Linux it will not detect my device as a Serial Interface, if i make dmesg i can see my device.

```
[  960.033788] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[  960.182977] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=28e9, idProduct=018a, bcdDevice= 2.00
[  960.182981] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  960.182982] usb 1-6: Product: USB CDC
[  960.182983] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: NETUM
[  960.182984] usb 1-6: SerialNumber: 00000000011C
[  960.234125] cdc_acm: probe of 1-6:1.0 failed with error -22
[  960.234156] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
```

How can i setup my system that Linux detect the device as a Serial Interface to collect the data from the Serial Port.

The goal is that a python program, detect the port and receive the data from the serial device

I use following python script to will get the serial ports
`ports = [tuple(p) for p in list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())]` and get as output `[]` so the list is empty and no port is found.

When i execute the lsusb command i get

```
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            2 Communications
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x28e9 
  idProduct          0x018a 
  bcdDevice            2.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0044
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower              456mA
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         0
      bInterfaceCount         2
      bFunctionClass          2 Communications
      bFunctionSubClass       2 Abstract (modem)
      bFunctionProtocol       0 
      iFunction               0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Abstract (modem)
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 AT-commands (v.25ter)
      iInterface              0 
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               1.10
      CDC Call Management:
        bmCapabilities       0x03
          call management
          use DataInterface
        bDataInterface          1
      CDC ACM:
        bmCapabilities       0x02
          line coding and serial state
      CDC Union:
        bMasterInterface        0
        bSlaveInterface         1 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
```

best regards
Patrick

Comment: Do you get a `/dev/ttyACM0` or similar when the device is plugged in? What is the result of `serial.tools.list_ports.comports()`?  Please [edit] your question to provide requested information.

Comment: It seems the cdc_acm's device probe failed with error `-EINVAL`. Could you show the output of `lsusb -v -d 28e9:018a`?

Comment: When i execute the lsusb command i get: i put it in the problem description